# Is there a way to transfer ownership of a tamed pet in Minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

In minecraft, there are many pets you can tame, in mostly different biomes. If you bring one of your pets that is already tamed to your base, can you somehow transfer ownership of the pet to one of the other players in your game?

Comment: @TheUselessPerson, what do you mean by eating a potato your pet will disappear into an explosion, do you maybe mean if you feed it a potato?

Comment: I assume your talking about in a survival scenario?

Comment: @FabianRöling this is the link that i mentioned :), be sure to read all the other comments!

Comment: @padfoot That's an automatic comment for close votes.